# Using supervisor and gunicorn to start up django-celery processes?

Tags: python, django, celery, gunicorn, supervisord

Confusion!

Its easy to launch django using supervisor, such as below - based on a tutorial I found:

supervisord.conf:

```
[program:gunicorn]
command=/home/me/.virtualenvs/app/bin/gunicorn app.wsgi:application --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 ;
```

Yet celery seems to require its own startup method:

```
celery -A app worker -l info
```

So in my ignorance/confusion it appears I have to either start with Gunicorn or Celery. Obviously I'm confused since no doubt many use celery within Supervisor.

Where am I going wrong? How do I use supervisor to start up a celery-django app within Gunicorn?

Comment: I'm guessing for your actual problem here so let me know if this doesn't help. This will tell you where to find the celery command: `type -a celery`. Usually it's in the bin folder of your virtualenv. You don't need gunicorn to run celery inside supervisor.

Comment: Since I asked this question, I've made a bit of progress with my "misunderstanding". Does running a celery worker create a django instance within itself? Otherwise I've started both a gunicorn/django instance and a celery instance, assuming the django instance cooperates with celery instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
celery -A app worker -l info
```

The command above will start an instance of the celery worker in the foreground.

There is [an example supervisor configuration available in the celery source](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/extra/supervisord/) if you'd like to use supervisor to daemonize the worker. Supervisor can manage multiple programs, so you can use it to manage gunicorn and one or more instances of celery worker if you'd like.

The celery worker runs as its own process. It connects to a broker (such as redis) and waits for tasks on a queue that you configure. These tasks would be sent from your django app.

The following tutorial does a very good job of explaining how to configure supervisor to launch and manage a celery worker. https://realpython.com/blog/python/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/

Comment: Thank you very much will check that.